# Using oAuth to retrieve tweets of a particular ID (equivalent to a page in facebook)

Tags: twitter

I need to know as to how to implement oAuth in an iphone application.

I have already gone through lot many posts but none of them shows as to How to retrieve tweets from a user profile (like we access facebook wallposts). I tried using an example named bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone but all it does is show the Login prompt and posts a sample Twit at my Twitter profile.

I need to make an application where

1. the user can view twits for a particular page (same as accessing the wall post for a Page)
2. Post tweets that will appear on his profile or if possible then also at the profile page for given ID

I was able to fetch the tweets for a particular id using http://search.twitter.com/search.json?ID but may be due to closing of Basic authentication it does not return to me tweets older than a specific time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter search API is not meant to retrieve the tweets from one particular user, even though it does seem to work (up to a certain point back in time). As far as I know the search API does not need authentication, so you're not in trouble regarding the deprecation of Basic authentication there.

To retrieve the tweets for a user, you need to [retrieve their timeline](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline). Be sure to use OAuth authentication, as indeed Basic authentication no longer works now.

Check out http://dev.twitter.com/ for more information. The API is documented quite well. You mention basic authentication, so perhaps you could start with http://dev.twitter.com/pages/basic_to_oauth to get you going?